# pthread and private data

Tags: c, pthreads

How can I use pthreads in this situation? The code receives requests from stdin and return the results based on some rules. But when I create a thread, the value of id and url is shared by all the threads. Example:

```
void * filter(void * data){
        int id;
        char url[1024];
        sscanf((char *) data, "%d %1024s", &id, url);
        sleep(id);
        printf("%s\n", url);
}

while(fgets(line, BUFFER, stdin)!=NULL)
   pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &filter, (void *) line);
```

--- Received from stdin

1 one
2 two
3 three
4 four
5 five

--- Output

one
three
four
five
five

-- But the results must be

one
two
three
four
five

There is a way to solve it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have it, all the threads get passed a pointer to the same data, and `fgets` will overwrite that data each time it is called. So your output will be a bit random, and possibly corrupt.

You can hand a copy of the line read to each thread, and have each thread free it (for example).

```
while (fgets(...))
  pthread_create(..., (void*)strdup(line));
```

In the thread procedure, you should check that the passed in data is not null (could happen if `strdup` failed to allocate sufficient memory for the copy), and add:

```
free(data);
```

once you're done working with it.

Having a separate (static) buffer for each thread would work too, but you'd have to know how many you're going to be starting beforehand (or do some dynamic re-allocations or something like that).

Comment: +1 for elegant solution. The thread procedure should also check that the argument is not `NULL`, since `strdup` may have failed due to insufficient memory.

Answer (score 1):

It's the line variable that is shared. You have a race condition where the line buffer is filled with the next line before the thread can process the buffer. You must allocate a new buffer to be passed to each thread.